# Android Studio - SQLite insert isn't inserting multiple columns

Tags: android, sqlite

TL;DR: I don't think I'm using `put()` and `insert()` in a SQLite database in android studio correctly.
EDIT: I'm also getting this exception, so I think my error is somewhere in the creation of the database

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) table yarns has no column named _id
```

I am making an inventory application using a SQLite database.  However, it seems my insert isn't adding the data to each column. My database handler has all the necessities such as the naming of the table, columns, database version.

Here is my DBHandlers onCreate(), which I made following a tutorial.

```
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "yarnInfo.db";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "yarns";
// Shops Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
private static final String KEY_BRAND_NAME = "brand_name";
private static final String KEY_YARN_NAME = "yarn_name";
private static final String KEY_COLOR = "color";
private static final String KEY_FIBER = "fiber";
private static final String KEY_BALLS_AVAILABLE = "balls_available";
private static final String KEY_YARDAGE = "yardage";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + KEY_BRAND_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_YARN_NAME + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_COLOR + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_FIBER + " TEXT, "
            + KEY_BALLS_AVAILABLE + " DOUBLE, "
            + KEY_YARDAGE + " DOUBLE " + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}
```

Add to database function within my database handler.

```
public void addYarn(Yarn yarn) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_ID,yarn.getID());
    values.put(KEY_BRAND_NAME, yarn.getBrandName()); // Yarn Brand Name
    values.put(KEY_YARN_NAME, yarn.getYarnName()); // Yarn Name
    //db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    values.put(KEY_COLOR, yarn.getColor()); // Yarn Color
    values.put(KEY_FIBER, yarn.getFiber()); // Yarn Fiber
    values.put(KEY_BALLS_AVAILABLE, yarn.getBallsAvailable());
    values.put(KEY_YARDAGE, yarn.getYardage()); // Yarn yardage

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
}
```

If I uncomment the first db.insert(...) between yarn name and yarn color, I can read the brand name and yarn name.

Using my database handler this is how I'm adding in the yarn in my `mainActivity`.

```
    myDB.addYarn(new Yarn(1, "Red Heart", "Comfy", "Red", "100% Acrylic", 5.3, 400.0));
    myDB.addYarn(new Yarn(2, "Baron", "Baby", "Blue", "100% Acrylic", 3, 400.0));
    myDB.addYarn(new Yarn(3, "Knit Picks", "Lux", "Purple", "100% Silk", 2, 50));
```

And I'm showing a listView of the yarns using "brand_name - yarn_name".  But I cannot add the color, fiber, or anything else. This fuction is in my `mainActivity` and populates the listView.

```
public void refreshDB() {
    final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
    final Cursor data = myDB.getCursor();
    Toast.makeText(this, "count:" + myDB.findLastID(),     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

if (data.getCount() == 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "There are no contents in this list!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        theList.add(data.getString(1) + " - " + data.getString(2));
        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, theList);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, yarnView.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

Again, when I uncomment that db.insert(...) I get the list of the inserted yarns and a toast of "count=3". When I leave it as is, I get a "count=0" and no list.  I also cannot add another column to the list. (My onclicklistener isn't working either, if you see any issues with that... I want to send the ID to another activity to display more details about a yarn)

E.g. This won't work, the app crashes.

```
theList.add(data.getString(1) + " - " + data.getString(2)" - " + data.getString(3));
```

So I don't think the insert is adding in all the columns. Where might my issue be if it's not here?

Thanks for any help you have.

Comment: What is the database schema? your content values keys should match the columns in the database schema.

Comment: You're missing `,` in the schema after some columns i.e. `+ KEY_YARN_NAME + " TEXT"` should be `+ KEY_YARN_NAME + " TEXT, "`

Comment: Okay, I've fixed that.  It's still not working, any more suggestions? I've changed the listView to theList.add(data.getString(1) + " - " + data.getString(3)); and while it's not crashing, I still get a count=0 toast

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats right - your current entries will still have null entries (is it crashing because of `NullPointerException`? stacktrace would be handy), try uninstalling app and pushing to phone/emulator again.

Comment: YES! It works after I changed the database version number. Thank you so much!